# Convert redshift array with escaped quotes to super type

Tags: amazon-redshift

In redshift, this select

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(JSON_SERIALIZE(after), 'works', 'string') as works...
```

returns something like this:

```
[{\"id\": \"Barclays\", \"selected\": true, \"displayName\": \"Barclays\"}, {\"id\": \"some_other_bank\", \"selected\": true, \"displayName\": \"some_other_bank\"}]
```

but I want to return this:

```
['Barclays', 'some_other_bank']
```

Is there an easy way to do this? How do I unescape these strings?

**EDIT**

So it just can't be a CTE. It has to be a materialized table. Why is this?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example, with a piece of sample data and a query that compiles. Thank you.